# Error wanting to install ubuntu 23.04

Tags: boot, system-installation, hash

I want to install ubuntu on my HP laptop, victus model, and when I start the installer, I get the following error:

[image]

pc specs:
R7 5800hs
Rtx3050
NVME Samsung MZVL2512HCJQ